# ActionMailer and Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, actionmailer

I have a rails actionMailer contact form which send emails but doesn't check if it dosen't  check the form for errors.
If I send an incorrect email: `ewfw` as opposed to a correct email: `test@test.com`
they both send, if the form is blank no email will get sent, and no error message comes up as well, but the notification alart works if the email get sent.

Any help would be appreciated.

*models/support.rb*

```
class Support
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :email, :sender_name, :support_type, :content
  # to deal with form, you must have an id attribute
  attr_accessor :id, :email, :sender_name, :support_type, :content

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    @attributes[key]
  end

  def to_key
  end

  def save
    if self.valid?
      Notifier.support_notification(self).deliver!
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

*controllers/supports_controller.rb*

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # id is required to deal with form
    @support = Support.new(:id => 1)



  end

  def create
    @support = Support.new(params[:support])
    if @support.save
      redirect_to('/contact', :notice => "Your message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You must fill all fields."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

*views/support/form_.html.erb*

```
<% form_for @support, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>


  <p>
    <%= f.label "Name" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :sender_name, "size" => 37 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Email" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :email, "size" => 37 %><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Subject" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.select :support_type, options_for_select(["Hire", "General", "Collaboration"]) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Details" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :content, "rows" => 3, "cols" => 27  %>
  </p>
  <p><br />
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

*Initializers/mailer.rb*

```
# config/initializers/mailer.rb
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true #default value
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true

ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {

:tls => true,
:address => 'smtp.test.com',
:port => 587,
:domain => 'test.com',
:user_name => 'test@test.com',
:password => '#',
:authentication => 'login',
:openssl_verify_mode=>nil,
:enable_starttls_auto => true


}
```

Comment: I would also be very careful about email forms like this. They are an attraction to bots and spammers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use an additional validator to validate that the email is in the proper format.

It could look something like this:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
```

More information can be found here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of